# Vue app.js file is randomly returning HTML

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a vue application that renders a web form.

Recently, I've begun having issues where the form won't load, and this message will show up in the console:

> The resource from “app.js” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”)
>   mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).

Fair enough.  I just need to make sure the file is returned with the correct mime type.  Easy peesy.

Nope.

As it turns out, when this error occurs, it's because app.js is *literally returning HTML*: https://prnt.sc/pn5cyq

Coincidentally, the HTML it's returning is the contents of my index.html: https://prnt.sc/pn5fig

If that weren't enough, it does this randomly.  When you refresh the page, sometimes app.js returns correctly.  There's no rhyme or reason to it.  When it does return correctly the nonce in the file name stays the same until the next time the error occurs.  When this happens, a subsequent refresh does not always fix the issue.  Sometimes it does.  Sometimes it takes multiple refreshes.  As I said, it's totally random.

I've been able to replicate this issue in Chrome, Safari, and Firefox, so it doesn't seem an issue with browsers or extensions.  This issue only occurs when I'm in production mode.  It seems to be an issue with how vue is compiling the production app.js.

I tried upgrading vue and the vue compiler to version 2.6.10, but that had no impact.

I'm at a loss.  SOS!  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you please provide your code?!

Comment: Oh gosh...what part of the code?  I mean, I didn't write the portion that actually generates the app.js file.  That stuff is native to vue and its dependecies.

Comment: What is your back end ? Can you provide the code ?

Comment: I've seen this in the past when someone is calling an endpoint that returns a view (html or some sort of template like a php file). If you're able to, check the back end route that your app.js is calling and see what it's returning. Maybe your app.js is calling the wrong route. 

Try to provide some code if you can, that'll make it way easier. The app.js file you're looking at has a version number. There should be another app.js file in your project somewhere or at least another JS file that has been compiled to this app.js file.